# Корень в слове "футбол"

Tags: однокоренные-слова, корень-слова

Проводили разбор слова "футбол", определили корень - "футбол".
Школьный учитель (и ряд источников в интернете) считают, что в этом слове два корня "фут" + "бол". Не могу этого понять... Это какие-то недавние изменения в языке?
И теперь многие иностранные слова стали иметь несколько корней? (рюкзак, бутерброд, бюстгальтер)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Надо различать этимологический и морфемный анализ

1) Морфемный анализ

Это **непроизводное  заимствованное слово,** которое не делится в русском языке на морфемы

**ФУТБОЛ**,  м. [англ. football] Спортивная игра, в которой игроки каждой из двух команд ударами ног стремятся забить мяч в ворота противника.

Футбол –  **заимствованное слово**, так как в английском языке уже существует слово football. Метод заимствования – транскрипция. Такие слова не делятся на морфемы.

Транскрипция (фонетический способ) – заимствование словарной единицы, при котором сохраняется ее звуковая форма.

[Методы заимствования](https://studopedia.ru/14_16771_puti-i-sposobi-zaimstvovaniya-leksiki-osnovnie-priznaki-zaimstvovannoy-leksiki-osvoenie-zaimstvovannih-slov-russkim-yazikom.html)

2) Этимологический анализ

Происходит от английского football букв. «ножной мяч», из foot «нога» + ball «мяч». Слово встречается в английском с XV века.

Answer (score 0):

Это вопрос условности: следует ли при членении слова (1) рассматривать его структуру с опорой на этимологию (здесь: два английских корня) или выяснять, (2) есть ли в *русском* языке слова с корнями, соответствующими выделяемым частям. Судя по этому материалу (Потиха З.А. Современное русское словообразование. – М.: Просвещение, 1970), принимается *второе* (см. параграф НЕПРОИЗВОДНЫЕ ИНТЕРНАЦИОНАЛЬНЫЕ СЛОВА).

> *Непроизводным является такое интернациональное слово, которое, несмотря на то что генетически состоит из двух-трех компонентов, в
>   синхронном аспекте **не содержит ни одного знаменательного для
>   русского языка слова или корня**. Следовательно, слова типа географ,
>   телеграф, телефон, биолог, кардиолог, телевизор, автобус и т. п. в
>   современном русском языке **не членятся**.*
>   https://studfile.net/preview/1771880/page:26/

В нашем случае нужно решить, усматривать ли в словах "**фут**" (мера длины) и "**бол**ельщик" (первоначально "болейщик") корни "фут" и "бол", тем самым признавая их  "знаменательными" для русского языка (в свете приведённой формулировки). Формально такое возможно, но вопрос "знаменательности" упирается в этимологию: без этимологического анализа носитель русского языка не воспринимает меру "фут" как длину *стопы*, а слово "болельщик" подсознательно полагает однокоренным с "*болезнью*" и с глаголом "болеть". Поэтому есть основания **не** членить слово "футбол" на отдельные корни. Вряд ли эту ситуацию может изменить слово "футзал" (футбол в крытом помещении, мини-футбол), поскольку фут- является просто *сокращением* от "футбол".